# Best approach to change variable value outside of Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am searching for the best approach to change Vue variable value outside of component. I'm using [Vue webpack](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) as well.

I have created a project using vue webpack.
Inside its default *App.vue* file, I have a variable. For example, let's take **showModal** and its default value is **false**.
Then I built it in a single javascript file.

```
<button>Register</button> {{-- event button --}}
<div id="guest"></div> {{-- Here I'm rendering my template --}}

<script src="{{ asset('js/vue-js/guest.js') }}"></script> {{-- builded Javascript file --}}
```

And the problem is that I want to change my **showModal** variable to **true**, but the event button it is not on my component template.

What is the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: If you change the value from a parent component, utilizing one-way data flow approach, you can use `props`. Otherwise, if it is from -let's say- kind of sibling components, you can use store like vuex.

Comment: @vahdet Best approaches wise your right about props but if OP's application is not very big then you might want to consider just a general repository pattern instead as per the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, best approach wise it's prevalent to think about the relationships between your existing components and their relationships. So for instance if the information your trying to pass will be used in a direct sibling or further down the chain you could choose `props`.

If your dealing with two components that share no direct relationship other than there current state you will need to extrapolate to either using the repository pattern or Vuex (flux like state management library) where we can then pass a reference to state or into properties in the repository pattern.

```
FooRepository.js

export default class FooRepository {
  SomeRef
  ManyRef = []

  addRef(name) {
    this.someRef = name;
  }

  addRefs(names){
    this.ManyRef.push(names);
  }

}
```

The above can be instantiated in your App Layer and shared between your components using an instance property https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html

Dependent on your apps size it might be time to include Vuex where we can save a reference directly into our state and use it in a simmilar manner as the repo pattern. Though as it's an officially supported package the setup and use is much simpler:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    ref: null
  },
  mutations: {
    saveRef (state, compRef) {
      state.ref = compRef
    }
  }
})
```

This is a very basic store that shows how we could save a reference into it, we can then access this reference in our components once we've registered the store inside main. This can be done using `this.$store.state.ref`. These two approaches are considered the best approach over simple simple props and or something like the event emitter for components that share no direct relationship.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to access a vue component outside of vue you could register it to the window object and access it then from anywhere.

```
window.myVueComponent = new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Now you can access it from anywhere else with

```
window.myVueComponent.myValue = 123
```

But this "style" is called global namespace pollution for reasons.
;)

I think it is better to extend your vue app so that the button is also within the vue-handled components.

Comment: This isn't a good approach at all, if were going to extrapolate to the window object were almost always better off using something like localStorage or cookies as there less volatile. In fact I'd avoid the windows object in general in almost every modern framework.

Comment: me too. That's why i added the hint for namespace pollution. But you can not store a reference to a component in local storage or the cookie.

Comment: True, but he's only after the data which you can grab from either of the above on a components instantiation and then apply a watcher too. Though overall Vuex or repo pattern are going to best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Vue instance just for emitting, call it global event manager.

```
global.event = new Vue()
```

when you want to emit an event ( like modal )

```
global.event.$emit('close-modal', (optional msg))
```

when you want to close modal :

// In your component

```
created(){
    var App = this;
    global.event.$on('close-modal', (optional msg)=>{
         this.showModal = false;
    })
}
```

Similarly do it for opening the modal. If you are using the vue CDN (normal js file of vue), instead of `global.event` use `window.event` while creating and only `event` while using. In browser if a variable which is undeclared is used then it refers to the window object.

Comment: This is an answer, but again is not a recommended approach. Docs wise repository or vuex are the better approach.